# RedQueryBuilder error thrown when using "cardinality" : "MULTI"

Tags: redquerybuilder

Error message from console:

```
Uncaught com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException:
  Exception caught:
    Exception caught:
      Unknown editor com.redspr.redquerybuilder.core.shared.meta.Editor$TextEditor@37 
      38F3C4025EC78286963A0AE9DF90B56C.cache.html:912
      (anonymous function)
```

If I change it back to "ONE" it works normally, however, I would need the parens to replace the enclosing quotes for IN to work properly.

Here is what my config looks like:

```
types : [{
  "name" : "STRING",
  "editor" : "TEXT",
  "operators" : [
    {
      "name" : "=",
      "label" : "Equals",
      "cardinality" : "ONE"
    },
    {
      "name" : "<>",
      "label" : "Not Equal To",
      "cardinality" : "ONE"
    },
    {
      "name" : "<",
      "label" : "Less Than",
      "cardinality" : "ONE"
    },
    {
      "name" : ">",
      "label" : "Greater Than",
      "cardinality" : "ONE"
    },
    {
      "name" : "IN",
      "label" : "IN = comma-delimited list. ex: Tyson,Holyfield",
      "cardinality" : "MULTI"
    }
  ]
}]
```

This is a great tool btw! If I can allow the use of IN for the Where clause, it will fulfill all requirements for my implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid this isn't supported (text editor that splits out commas)... Only SelectEditor (need better name) supports MULTI.

This seems a reasonable feature though.

Worth creating a feature request on https://github.com/salk31/RedQueryBuilder ?

and maybe a bug report about poor error message?

Cheers

Sam

Comment: Thanks Sam. I can do a find and replace as an interim solution.